# Add input field into modal box by Collective

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

This code make below modal.

How can I add input field to this modal by Blade?

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['jobs.destroy', $job->id], 'method' => 'delete', 'class' => 'btn-group', 'id' => 'jobStop']) !!}
{!! Form::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-xs', 'onclick' => "return confirm('Are you sure you want stop?')"]) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

[image]

Comment: Form::text() ? What do you mean with 'by Blade'

Comment: Form::input..... are you using laravel collective? or just add it in html? I don't understand the issue here

Comment: use the docs when in doubt https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html

Comment: That is not a modal... That is a javascript [confirmation window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm)

Comment: It's not a modal, so you can not add input

Comment: ok thanks all.I will make code except Collective, it sometime make me confuse.. :(